# Dynamically change the color of an <li> with JavaScript

Tags: css, reactjs, styles, html-lists

This code is in React and I was wondering how is possible to change the `className` of this `li` to be the color passed by `color={project.get('color')}`

```
if (this.state.dropdown) {
  const projectsList = this.props.projects.map((project) => (
    <li className='u-cursor--pointer c-start-retro-line'
      color={project.get('color')}
      key={project.get('id')}
      onClick={() => this.handleProjectSelection(project.get('id'))} >
      {project.get('name') === 'default' ? 'No Project' : project.get('name')}
    </li>
  ))
```

Let's say the color of this `li` is #008CFF, (every color will be different) how can I make this the font color of the li?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `style` prop on your `<li>`, like this:

```
   <li 
     style={{color: project.get('color')}}
     className={...} />
```